# wildcard on javascript (perhaps it's no brainer?)

Tags: javascript

```
player.obj.speed = 20;
computer1.obj.speed = 20;
computer2.obj.speed = 20;
```

into

```
*.obj.speed =20; //once and for all!
```

I think my question here is clear enough to be understood.
I will install automation packages if needs... but I think there is simplest way that makes me facepalm...
anyway thanks!

Comment: make an array with [player, computer1, computer2], and loop each item and set those.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectArray = [ //Array of the objects (not their speeds as integers don't get passed by reference, but objects do)
    player.obj,
    computer1.obj,
    computer2.obj
]

function setAll(X)
{
    //Go over all the objects
    for(var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++)
    {
        objectArray[i].speed = X;
    }

}
```

This is pretty straightforward: make an array of the objects (which WILL update the original, as apposed to an array of integers or floats, etc). Then, when you want to change them, just go over the array and set each one's speed property.